# VirtualBox VT-x virtualization already in use

Tags: mac-osx, virtualbox, vagrant

- My host OS:  Mac OSX 10.8.2 (just upgraded from 10.8.1)
- Virtualbox:  4.2.0 rc80737
- Vagrant: 1.0.4

I just upgraded my OS with the latest OSX upgrade/patch.  Now, I'm unable to use my VMs:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine vag_1347774268.
>
> VT-x is being used by another hypervisor. (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).
>
> VirtualBox can't operate in VMX root mode. Please close all other virtualization programs. (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
>   Component: Console
>   Interface: IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}

I'm not running any other virtualization programs as far as I can tell.

Any ideas on how to remedy the situation?

Comment: Good question, wrong site.

Comment: @LucasKaufman: Couldn't you have pointed Domino at the better site ?

Comment: Which site?  I apologize, I thought VM issues would be here.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Please see the FAQ for a detailed explanation of what we do and do not cover here. For your question, you may wish to visit our sister site [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) (and be sure to read their FAQ as well).

Comment: @Domino It's a bit of a gray area: If you're asking for yourself ("My Mac, at home") it really belongs on [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com) because it's an Apple-Specific problem.  If you're asking as part of work ("We upgraded my boss' mac and now VirtualBox doesn't work" or "We upgraded our Mac labs at the university and now the Windows VirtualBox instances won't run") it's on-topic here too, but we don't have many Mac Heads so Ask Different might be a better place to try if your problem is Mac-Specific.

Comment: (Normally I'd also say it's best to ask the vendor about errors like this, but we're talking about VirtualBox, and getting support out of Oracle will cost you your first born, a kidney, and possibly your car... After which they'll tell you "Idunno!" because your question isn't about their database products :)

Comment: Are the downvotes because the question was asked in the wrong place? Or because the question is worded badly? I the question is likely to get migrated to another stackexchange site, don't downvote it simply for that reason, because the votes will transfer too.

Comment: And if you do downvote, PLEASE explain why, so the original poster can fix it and better the site and community.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known issue](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10965) - there's a fix due.

Comment: Affects all Ivy Bridge Macs with 10.8.2 who have applied the Bios/firmware update that came with the 10.8.2 update.

Comment: It appears the fix is out.  Thanks for the link to the ticket.